# how to place the diamond shaped boxes adjacent to each other without any gaps?

Tags: html, css

how to place the diamond shaped boxes adjacent to each other without any gaps?
i want red diamond shaped boxes to appear within the gaps instead just below one another..how to do it?

```css
    .container{width:600px;border:1px solid red;float:none;margin:0 auto;}
     .diamond {
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
background: #1eff00 ;
 /* Rotate */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
/* Rotate Origin */
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
-moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
-ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
-o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
transform-origin: 0 100%;
 float:left;
 margin: 0 50px 50px 0;
 }
  .diamond2{background:red;}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="diamond"></div>
    <div class="diamond"></div>
    <div class="diamond"></div>
    <div class="diamond diamond2"></div>
    <div class="diamond diamond2"></div>
    <div class="diamond diamond2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please place your code in a runnable snippet?

Comment: like this you mean https://jsfiddle.net/ch06tj7p/2/ ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{width:600px;border:1px solid red;float:none;margin:0 auto;}
     .diamond {
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
background: #1eff00 ;
 /* Rotate */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
/* Rotate Origin */
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
-moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
-ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
-o-transform-origin: 0 100%;
transform-origin: 0 100%;
 float:left;
 margin: 0 60px 60px 0;
 }
  .diamond2{background:red;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="diamond"></div>
    <div class="diamond"></div>
    <div class="diamond"></div>
    <div class="diamond diamond2"></div>
    <div class="diamond diamond2"></div>
    <div class="diamond diamond2"></div>
</div>
```